# disabling the Yellow-Black gradient color on scrolling at the ends of listview, scrollview, horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

We know that, when we scroll a listview at bottom or top of the list, we will see gradient color of yellow and black. Same thing will happen for ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView also at the edges. I want to disable the color when user scrolling these views.

is it possible to disable that color as we disable scrollbars with property

`android:scrollbars="none"`

If anybody know the solution please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can or really want to disable those colors. They were added to the OS as a way to indicate to the user that they have reached the end of the list.  Altering fundamental pieces of the UI is discouraged as it produces a unfamiliar user experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yellow-black gradient color is actually appears when you over scroll the scroll views.

It can be eliminated by using below code in XML file of ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

It will work for android 2.3 and above. I don't for below API levels.

Comment: hey this property is working for yellow but when i scroll the listview white color will be seen in place of yellow so what can i do for hidden white color also??

Comment: while scrolling, you can remove the white fade with android:fadingEdge="none"

Comment: The code is not working. I tried it on 5.0 Lollipop.

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:fadingEdge="none"` in `<ListView>`

Comment: I am using HorizontalScrollView, i tried fadingEdge=none but still showing gradient color.

Comment: use HorizontalScrollView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);